# Coming from Flutter, Android Studio and Android SDK is missing in WIN10

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio

I am coming from flutter community to test react-native for learning purposes.

I am trying to setup but while android studio and sdk are installed, react-native doctor says its not installed. I dont know why its happening.

Here are screenshots and some texts about my problem.

> 

```
PS C:\Users\Elyas\rn\AwesomeProject> npx react-native doctor
⠙ Running diagnostics...* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 34.0.0

Errors:   3
Warnings: 1

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

When i press e, after the clean uninstall of android studio and sdk, it just downloads and installs android studio.

```
PS C:\Users\Elyas\rn\AwesomeProject> Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
ANDROID_HOME                   C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT               C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Roaming
ChocolateyInstall              C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
ChocolateyLastPathUpdate       133476540820612353
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   DESKTOP-7AJASMR
ComSpec                        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE                      C:
HOMEPATH                       \Users\Elyas
JAVA_HOME                      C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local\jdk-11.0.2
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER                    \\DESKTOP-7AJASMR
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8
OneDrive                       C:\Users\Elyas\OneDrive
OS                             Windows_NT
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.CPL
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6
PROCESSOR_REVISION             8e0c
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\Elyas\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME                    Console
SystemDrive                    C:
SystemRoot                     C:\Windows
TEMP                           C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                            C:\Users\Elyas\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN                     DESKTOP-7AJASMR
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      DESKTOP-7AJASMR
USERNAME                       Elyas
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\Elyas
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH          C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir                         C:\Windows
WSLENV                         WT_SESSION:WT_PROFILE_ID:
WT_PROFILE_ID                  {61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}
WT_SESSION                     96248d65-2a2c-4533-8f65-a1388f86cc99
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN              1


PS C:\Users\Elyas\rn\AwesomeProject> npx react-native upgrade
success You are on the most recent stable release of React Native: 0.73.1 .
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried everything i search for in the internet.

Comment: There's a bunch of questions about that on SO already, were none of those the same as your problem? If not: talk about that in your post. And if you didn't use your error text to search for similar posts yet, do that first.